# サブネットマスクとワイルドカードマスクの違いは何ですか？

Tags: network

ネットワークではアドレス範囲の指定にサブネットマスクとワイルドカードマスクがありますが、これらの違いはなんですか？

`192.168.1.0/24`は`255.255.255.0`でも`0.0.0.255`でも変わらないのでサブネットマスクがあれば、ワイルドカードマスクは必要ないのではないかと思っています。

Answer (score 1):

こんにちは、はじめまして。

一例となると思いますが、二つを組み合わせて、CISCOのネットワーク機器でIPベースでののアクセス制御(ACL)を実現するために組み合わせて利用されているようです。

サブネットマスクは左から右にビットが連続している必要が(RFC4632 3.1)あり、ワイルドカードマスクにはその仕様がありません。そのため特定のオクテットが奇数のサブネットには通信を通すなどの制御ができます。

必要かどうかというと多分に主観的な話となりますが、実装されている処理系が存在するということは、実務上は必要なケースがあるのではないでしょうか。

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4632#section-3.1
https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/app_ntwk_services/waas/waas/v511/command/reference/cmdref/ext_acl.pdf